What timezone does the Google API use for segmenting metrics by date?
Consider this query for querying keyword metrics daily
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/query/overview

         SELECT 
            ad_group_criterion.criterion_id,
            ad_group_criterion.type,
            ad_group_criterion.keyword.text,
            ad_group_criterion.keyword.match_type,
            ad_group_criterion.status,
            metrics.clicks,
            metrics.impressions,
            metrics.average_cost,
            metrics.cost_micros,
            metrics.average_cpm,
            metrics.average_cpc,
            metrics.ctr
        FROM keyword_view
        WHERE
            segments.date DURING TODAY


What timezone does the Google API use for segmenting metrics by date?
This was asked here: https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/XprkF_vnPmA?pli=1
But the answer is not clear.
I've asked the same question on the google developers video as well:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwyFNi7wRgU
I've tried reading the docs on google ads but couldn't find a clear answer
